# Delete from numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays in NumPy

```
a = np.array([])
b = np.array([])
```

These arrays are being populated throughout the code with cohesive values. But now I want to delete elements from both arrays where values in `a` are greater than the number `5`.

I guess it's something like

```
a = a[~a>5]
```

but I don't know how to delete the element with exact same index in the array `b`.

Comment: you can set an index `ix = a <= 5` and then `a = a[ix]` and `b = b[ix]` (or do it in one line `a = a[a <= 5]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.extract` to select the specific elements and reassigned to your array again :

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> x=np.extract(x<5,x)
>>> x
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

> **numpy.extract(condition, arr)**
>
> Return the elements of an array that satisfy some condition.

You can also use indexing for such task :

```
>>> x = np.array([3,4,7,11,0,34,6,1,3,4,2])
>>> x[x<5]
array([3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2])
>>> np.extract(x<5,x)
array([3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2])
```